# Turn pivot table into regular dataframe

Tags: pandas

How can I get this pivot table:

```
                        mean
                   points_num
round     position            
1         FWD        2.445283
          MID        1.628571
          DEF        2.378571
2         FWD        3.000000
          MID        2.651351
          DEF        1.930435
```

`df.columns`:

```
[108 rows x 1 columns]
MultiIndex([('mean', 'points_num')],
           )
```

---

And change it into a dataframe like so:

```
Round   FWD       MID        DEF
1       2.445283  1.628571  2.378571
2       3.000000  2.651351  1.930435
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
pivot_df.iloc[:,0].unstack('position')
```

However, you can probably be better off using `pivot_table` on the original dataframe:

```
df.pivot_table(index='round', column='position', 
               values='points_num', aggfunc='mean'
              )
```